# Thymeleaf + Spring MVC : Update not working , update is creating new record

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Below is my controller class. The update is not happening , each and everytime i update a new record is being created . I'm using Thymeleaf templates. Am i doing it the wrong way ?

SystemConfigController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/systemconfig")
public class SystemConfigController {

@Autowired
private SystemConfigService systemConfigService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findAll(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("config", systemConfigService.findAll());
    return "systemconfig";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveSystemConfig(SystemConfig systemConfig) {
        this.systemConfigService.save(systemConfig);
    return "redirect:/systemconfig/";
}

@RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
public String editSystemConfig(@PathVariable("id") Integer schemaId, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("config", this.systemConfigService.findOne(schemaId));
    return "addsystemconfig";
}

@RequestMapping("/view/{id}")
public String viewSystemConfig(@PathVariable("id") Integer schemaId, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("config", this.systemConfigService.findOne(schemaId));
    return "viewsystemconfig";
}


@RequestMapping("/delete/{id}")
public String delete(@PathVariable("id") Integer schemaId, Model model) {
    this.systemConfigService.delete(schemaId);
    return "redirect:/systemconfig/";
}
```

}

Comment: check if your `systemConfig` in your `saveSystemConfig` method has set the primary key.

Comment: Do you mean that you succeed to create a new record on DB, but you can't see it on your browser?